# Dynamic _Layout page without the user logging in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, dynamic

I'm looking to put dynamic information in the _Layout.cshtml file. The menus that are rendered on screen should be different per user. I was trying to look at _LoginPartial in the default application, but unlike that page, I don't have a "Login" form on my page to send to a controller. In my MVC application, the user should already be logged in.

I'm trying to integrate it into our ERP solution that we have here that also has it's own web service. The user will log into that web service, be able to click a link on the page and be directed to my application. Logging in is handled by our ERP solution. At that time, my menu should be rendered differently based on the user's permissions. So in practice, by the time the user accesses my application, they should already be "logged in", and never not be "logged in".

The ERP solution we have I believe allows us access to the user's id number (among only a few other items) that is passed among it's pages. I can query the database to get any other required information that I need (ex. Are they a staff member or a student?). But in my application, I don't know how to get that information and store it in session prior to the _Layout loading.

Comment: And just to be clear here, I have looked through forum posts on this particular subject for a couple weeks now. I've used places like this to get my info and I do think I've learned much considering I started this project not knowing anything. I've been working on it for some time now. I just don't want to give the impression that I've not researched anything. I have worked on this project for many months now. I just decided for this to be my first post. So even if it's a nudge in the right direction will be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are down-votes without any comment explaining why.  Your question is quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're mixing the abstract idea of presentation (layout) and logic.  The layout should almost be exclusively html.  If you need any type of dynamic parts in there, I'd recommend doing exactly what the default MVC template does and either call a partial or an action `Html.RenderAction()` which would provide the *logic* you need for them to be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I want to keep my html seperate from my c#. I just wanted to perform queries and such to change what users saw. I was confused because in a default application, the controller that house all the logic is accessed when the user posts a form. I never had a form to post so I didn't know how to trigger a controller with no interaction from the user. The user just navigates to my application and thats it.

I will look for more on Html.RenderAction() and Html.Action() and see if I can find a way to perform logic prior to rending the menu.